# Testing if now if between two times that span midnight

Tags: powershell, timespan

I've tried searching for this, but I'm at a loss... I can find answers for other languages, but not for PowerShell.

Basically, I want to test if the time now is between 21:15 and 5:45.

I'm pretty sure I need to use New-TimeSpan - but, for the life of me, I just can't work it out.

I'd share my test code, but I think I'm so far away from the answer that it wouldn't be of any help.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to special case it, if time2 < time1, you need a separate set of if's. Or, you can add 24 hours to time2 if time2 < time1, and then check both "now" and "now + 24h" to see if either is between time1 and time2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Get-Date` to create `DateTime` objects describing those thresholds as points in time on todays date, then test if the time right now is before the early one or after the late one:

```
$now = Get-Date
$morning = Get-Date -Date $now -Hour 5 -Minute 45
$evening = Get-Date -Date $now -Hour 21 -Minute 15

$isWithinRange = $now -le $morning -or $now -ge $evening
```

Answer (score 2):

**If this is purely about the *time of day* and you don't need any *date* calculations**, you can do the following, relying on the fact that for padded number *strings* lexical sorting equals chronological sorting:

```bash
# Get the current point in time's time of day in 24-hour ('HH') format.
# Same as: [datetime]::Now.ToString('HH\:mm')
$timeNow = Get-Date -Format 'HH\:mm'

$timeNow -ge '21:15' -or $timeNow -le '05:45'
```

---

As [xjcl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2111778/xjcl) notes, you can apply this *lexical-comparison technique* to full timestamps too; e.g.

```bash
$now = Get-Date
# Create a text-sortable representation of the date down to the minute.
$sortableNowString = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm'
# Create a reference timestamp in the same format.
$sortableRefString = (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' 13:00' # fixed time of day
# Compare: will only be $true after 1 PM
$sortableNowString -gt $sortableRefString
```

As with string format `HH\:mm` for times of day, this hinges on picking a date format whose *lexical* sorting is equivalent to *chronological* sorting.

However, you *cannot* perform actual date/time *calculations* that way, such as determining the time span between two dates, or subtracting a time span from a date. Such operations require working with [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) (or [`[datetimeoffset]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset)) and [`[timespan]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) instances directly; e.g.:

```bash
$now = Get-Date

# Same as: $now.TimeOfDay, i.e. returns the time of day as a [timespan]
$now - $now.Date 

# Same as: $now.Date, i.e. returns the very start of the calendar
#          day as a [datetime]
$now - $now.TimeOfDay
```

Comment: You could even extend this to date calculations, `(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')`, and then compare that to the target string(s)

Comment: Good point, @xjcl, but note that this only works for _lexical comparisons_ (comparing and sorting), but not for actual date/time _calculations_, such as getting the time span between two dates. Please see my update.

Comment: Ah, I see your point now. I just wanted to run a script until a specific timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd have to check if you are in the range 23:00-04:00, crossing the midnight, you could:

```
$now=(Get-Date).TimeofDay
if ($now.TotalHours -ge 23 -or $now.TotalHours -lt 04)
{"In Range"}
else
{"Out of range"}
```